# NginX redirect if URL equals

Tags: url, redirect, if-statement, nginx

My issue is with NginX anf if (I know if is evil, but I need to use it).
I want to redirect the users coming to my website uon two conditions. If their IP matches and if the URL is exactly www.domain.com

Base is I have a webserver with 2 IPs and 2 domains. One for English, one for local language. I want to redirect everyone with a local IP to the local domain. (from domain.com to domain.hu)

What I've done so far: I've installed NginX with IP2Location and it works like a charm. Here is my "if" part of the nginx.conf

```
if ($ip2location_country_short ~ ^HU$)
            {
            set $my_var1 "${my_var1}B";
            }
    if ($request_uri ~ .*wonder*.*)
            {
            set $my_var1 "${my_var1}C";
            }
    if ($my_var1 = ABC)
            {
            #rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.hu last;
            }
```

What I want to achieve is: Use a variable called $my_var1 and use it to decide if I need to redirect the user or not. I've set it to "A" in the 1st place. 
In the first condition: If the user is from Hungary then make $my_var1 equal to "AB". Next I want to check if the user have written the ENG or the HU URL in the browser. I want to redirect the user if he wrote an exact URL of www.domain.com. If he did, then I set my $my_var1 to "ABC". And in the 3rd if, if the value of $my_var1 equals "ABC", then inicialise the redirection.

My problems are: I don't know how to check the URL. I found this problem while I wrote a PHP file to show me the value of $my_var1 after entering the site and it turned out the value of $my_var1 os always only "AB". I'm failing to check the URL. Can you please give me a description how to check the URL conataining text/equal to something

Comment: `but I need to use it` I bet you don't. It's not really clear what you are trying to do since you are checking if the request_uri contains wonde[r]* yet also saying they must be requesting the exact url `www.domain.com/` - how is it logically possible to match both conditions? You're also, currently, in exactly the circumstances "if is evil" warns not to do `The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in location context are return and rewrite last`.

Comment: Also the obvious first step is to have 2 server blocks - you should put your **whole** nginx server config in the question.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to google and the request_uri is what I've found to check the URL typed by the user. The main goal is just to redirect every user from Hungary from the domain.com to the domain.hu. If I check only the IP, then it goes into a redirection circle and unable to work. That's why I though that I'll check the URL as well to redirect the user only if he is from Hungary AND he wrote the wrong URL (domain.com). That wonder is just a part of the domain.com

Comment: I advise you not to do that at all. E.g. I live in Spain, my first language is English - it's infuriating to want to visit `example.com` and be unconditionally redirected to `example.es`. Real e.g. I can't access [godaddy's help pages](https://godaddy.com/help/english-1655) in English to link to them without being redirected to the spanish language site. If you want to redirect users from .com to .hu you should probably do that in your app, and only if the user hasn't already been redirected the other way (use a cookie). **You need to put your whole config in the question** to get an answer.

Comment: I'm not the owner of the website, so I won't decide what the customer wants, I can only give him hints. :)

Comment: Doesn't make it more right that the customer wants it - in any event it's just information/an opinion. However this wasn't a hint: **You need to put your whole config in the question**.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YHY6tTLz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done!

```
set $my_var A;

    if ($ip2location_country_short ~ ^HU$)
            {
            set $my_var "${my_var}B";
            }
    if ($http_host ~ .*domain.com.*)
            {
            set $my_var "${my_var}C";
            }
    if ($my_var = "ABC")
            {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://domain.hu last;
            }
```

Didn't think it will be this easy.....